# Stay connected on a network without Internet

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

I'm trying to connect to a Wi-Fi hotspot on Android 10 which has no available Internet connection. The problem is that as soon as I'm connected and the device detects there's no connection, it goes back to another connection with Internet available.

After looking up what I can do I've found this piece of code which supposedly forces staying:

```
val manager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
val mWifiLock: WifiManager.WifiLock = manager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "wifiLock")
if (! mWifiLock.isHeld) {
    mWifiLock.acquire()
}
```

Unfortunately, that code is deprecated and doesn't work anymore. So far, the only working solutions I've found was disabling the other networks. I've also found other threads on StackOverflow with the exact same problem, but those were created 1+ years ago so I figured I might ask this again.

Does anyone know of an updated way I can stay connected to this network?

This is the code I use for connecting to the hotspot btw:

```
val wifiNetworkSpecifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
        .setSsid(ssid)
        .setWpa2Passphrase(pass)
        .build()

val wifiRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
        .build()

val connectivity = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    override fun onUnavailable() {
        super.onUnavailable()
    }

    override fun onLosing(network: Network, maxMsToLive: Int) {
        super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive)
        listener(false)
    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
        super.onLost(network)
        listener(false)
    }

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        super.onAvailable(network)
        
        connectivity?.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
        //Code to force-stay
        listener(true)
    }
}

connectivity?.requestNetwork(wifiRequest, networkCallback)
```

Comment: turnout did u fix this? I'm facing the same issue, cry